# Scan for processes and do something when a specific is found

Tags: c++, windows, process

I want my C++ program to scan for processes and when a certain file.exe is running, I want my program to do something (irrelevant here). Could you help me with this task?

I found something on the internet. Is this ok ?

```
CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NAMEofTHEprocess_exe);
if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)return 0;
```

Can I use it in my program? I dont know what the Mutex is.

Comment: Uhm... the most common use case for this I can remember is a virus detecting when the antivirus is being loaded...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic enumeration of running processes in Windows:

```
#define  WINVER      0x0500
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#define  PSAPI_VERSION    1
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <sddl.h>

void ListProcesses()
{
  DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
  MEMORYSTATUSEX statex;

  statex.dwLength = sizeof(statex);

  ::GlobalMemoryStatusEx(&statex);

  ::EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded);
  cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < cProcesses; ++i)
    if(aProcesses[i] != 0)
      std::cout << "PID: " << aProcesses[i] << ", Name: " << getProcessNameByID(aProcesses[i]) << std::endl;
}
```

You can use the final name look-up with `getProcessNameByID` to make a decision. Here's the code for `getProcessPathNameByID`:

```
#include <tchar.h>

std::string getProcessNameByHandle(HANDLE hProcess)
{
  if (NULL == hProcess)
    return "<unknown>";

  TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");
  HMODULE hMod;
  DWORD cbNeeded;

  if (::EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod), &cbNeeded))
    ::GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, sizeof(szProcessName)/sizeof(TCHAR));

  return std::string(szProcessName);
}

std::string getProcessNameByID(DWORD processID)
{
  HANDLE      hProcess = ::OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, processID);
  std::string result   = getProcessNameByHandle(hProcess);
  ::CloseHandle(hProcess);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm completly new to c++. Always used Java and Eclipse (when needed to import/include something just pressed shift+o) and now I have a bit of a problem because the compilator screams that almost everything from this was not yet declared. Coudl You help me also with this ?

Comment: Oh, the standard library headers... add `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>` at the top, and you need to put the `getProcessNameByHandle` function first.

Comment: Already had them. Still get errors like this:
'MEMORYSTATUSEX' was not declared in this scope|

Comment: @shym: Strange, it's part of the [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366770(v=vs.85).aspx). Maybe it's a versioning problem, try saying `#define WINVER      0x0500`, `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500` and `#define PSAPI_VERSION 1` before you include `windows.h`.

Comment: Now i get this :

'
C:\Pliki\Projekty\CPP\Test\Test.cpp||In function 'void ListProcesses()':|
C:\Pliki\Projekty\CPP\Test\Test.cpp|31|error: '::EnumProcesses' has not been declared|
C:\Pliki\Projekty\CPP\Test\Test.cpp|36|error: 'getProcessNameByID' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Pliki\Projekty\CPP\Test\Test.cpp||In function 'std::string getProcessNameByHandle(void*)':|
C:\Pliki\Projekty\CPP\Test\Test.cpp|47|error: '::EnumProcessModules' has not been declared|
C:\Pliki\Projekty\CPP\Test\Test.cpp|48|error: '::GetModuleBaseName' has not been declared|'

Comment: Hey, you can check up the documentation on MSDN, you know... I forgot to mention two more headers, `#include <psapi.h>` and `#include <sddl.h>`.

Comment: i now have problem with the getProcessNameByID() and dont know what to do : / i think its something with the argument i pass to it, heres the code: http://pastebin.com/DceGzEhx and the error : error: invalid conversion from 'DWORD' to 'void*'|
error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::string getProcessNameByID(void*)'|

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to paste that second function. Edited!

Comment: Ok Man I'm really sorry but it still doesent work : / now getting a "undefined reference to EnumProcesses" : /

Comment: @shym: you need to link against Psapi.lib - but perhaps you should try to understand basics about how executable is built in C++ first (includes, libraries)? You will encounter plenty of small "problems" like this if you do not understand the process and only blindly copy what other submit to you.

Comment: Hmm, I forgot what you have to link this to, but you just need to find out the right library. It's some Windows library. Maybe you can find out on the internet, or I can look it up later!

Comment: @Suma: Sounds about right, thanks! The MSDN docs will say which library you need, just search for the function name.

Comment: Thx for all advices. I think I will do better now : )